# How do I create an actual ruler that is accurate in Pages?

Tags: pages

Looking for a way to add an accurate measurement ruler on all 4 sides of the document for everything we print, 2x sides in inches and 2x sides in cm. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Are you using pages on the web or on the iPad or ?? Pretty sure the answer is nope for the left and right margins, but I’m curious how close to this you have set up with the settings Apple designed in to the apps…